# Why does community.general.telegram (in Ansible) produce an error?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I want to configure an Ansible playbook, add some code for start a service and send a notification to Telegram but I am faced with the error shown below. I think this is not a typing error but some other error with the community general Telegram playbook. I have done this before without error. Now I am trying to reinstall new server, follow the same process but I get this error.

```
 ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.telegram'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbook/start.yml': line 10, column 6, but maybe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


   - name: send notify to telegram
     ^ here
```

**start.yml**

```
---
- name: testing playbook
  hosts: server
  tasks:
   - name: start apache service
     service:
      name: apache2
      state: started

   - name: send notify to telegram
     community.general.telegram:
      token: 'telegram token'
      api_args:
       chat_id: telegramid
       parse_mode: "markdown"
       text: "Apache Web service has been started!"
       disable_web_page_preview: True
       disable_notification: True
```

**Installation process**

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt install dirmngr -y
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y ansible
sudo ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
```

**Ansible Version**

```
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

**sudo ansible-galaxy collection install community.general**

```
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Skipping 'community.general' as it is already installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you also running the `ansible-playbook` with `sudo`? The same user should be used both for the galaxy install and the ansible playbook run.

Things seem correct otherwise. You can try an upgrade to see if it helps:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.general --upgrade
```

More info [in the ansible galaxy community.general docs](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/general).

Comment: got this error -> 
usage: ansible-galaxy [-h] [--version] [-v] TYPE ...
ansible-galaxy: error: unrecognized arguments: --upgrade

Comment: OK try first to install the collection without `sudo` and then run `ansible-playbook` also without `sudo`. Regarding the `--upgrade` parameter, I guess that it is available in a later version of `ansible-galaxy` than the one you have installed